# jquery datepicker losing focus when using extended key shortcuts

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have extended datepicker of jquery in a dialog and changed its shortcuts, the problem is when the page is reloaded, the date does not get selected by the shortcuts, whereas if I close the dialog and reopen it, then the shortcuts work fine.

I am not able to find the problem.
Here is the code snippet.

```
    $.extend($.datepicker, { customKeyPress: function (event) {
    var inst = $.datepicker._getInst(event.target);
    var c = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
    switch (c) {       
        case "t":
            // Today (same as Ctrl+Home).
            $.datepicker._gotoToday(event.target);
            break;
        case "+":
            // Increase day (same as Ctrl+Right).
            $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, +1, 'D');
            break;
        case "-":
            // Decrease day (same as Ctrl+Left).
            $.datepicker._adjustDate(event.target, -1, 'D');
            break;
    }
   }
  });


$('#datepicker').keypress(function (event) { 
    $.datepicker.customKeyPress(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the default date using $(document).ready() function.